# Vue JS maintaining route when linking to nested routes

Tags: vue.js

If component **A** is my app and I have a route that maps to component **B**. Then Component **B** has a **router-view** in it that I'd like to be able to switch between component **C** and component **D**.

When I link to component **C** or **D** it works but it renders the whole route again, so **B** is rendered again and I am scrolled to the top.

What is the best way to approach this? Nested Apps? Or is there a way to link to a subroute with it keeping the part of the route that isn't changing intact and not completely refresh it. So ideally just part of the webpage renders and the route changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component B shouldn't be re-drawing when you move between C and D unless you set `canReuse` to false: http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/pipeline/can-reuse.html

If you are being scrolled to the top it's probably because when the content of C or D disappears, the site height is reduced to just the header, and thus automatically scrolled up.  You could try making component B `height:100%` so it doesn't shrink

edit: nested routes actually solve this.  That way you are never actually re-routing to B, you're just navigating within the subroutes of B:

```
'/:param_one': {
    component: require('./RouteOne.vue'),
    name:'RouteOne',
    subRoutes:{
        '/:param_two':{
            component:require('./views/Dashboard/OtherRoute.vue'),
            name:'OtherRoute'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the route data transition is being called again on B, which sets loadingRouteData to true and bring up a loading spinner. From docs:

data is also called every time the route changes, even if the current component is reused, while activate is only called when component is newly created.

I guess I need to not reload the data if its just a subroute change. I have a route param I can check manually but what if there was no route param on B>

Comment: There is a route hook called `activate` that you can use instead of `data`.  This one won't be called again if the route is being re-used: http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/pipeline/activate.html

Comment: I think the problem with using that is the component will not be displayed until that transition resolves and it doesn't set loadingRouteData. Since my data is async it will stall changing routes rather than going right away with a loading spinner. I could get around this maybe by not returning the promise from the activation transition but just set my own loading attribute to true then false in the callback.

Comment: Yea it seems like an oversight that there is no `$loadingRouteData` equivalent implemented here... The component will not be displayed until the `activate` hook is resolved, so yea you'd have to skip the promise.  Maybe you could continue to use the `data` hook but only load your data if it hasn't been loaded before, otherwise return immediately?

Comment: Yup that is my current solution. My route has a slug parameter that is used to load a model. So I check if ($route.params.slug == this.model.slug) and if its true I do not reload the data. If the route parameter slug does not match the currently loaded models slug then I do a reload. This works fine, just seems like a bandaid.

Comment: Evan has a discussion open about trying to simplify the current transition lifecycle, there is definitely room to improve: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/321

Comment: Wait a minute, now that I think about it using nested routers would eliminate this issue.  Just put a `<router-view>` in component B and make another nested router for the next route param. Then you aren't reloading B you're just reloading the data relevant to C or D

Comment: I edited my answer for this I think that resolves your issue

Comment: I have been using nested routes. I was finding that if I click on a v-link to OtherRoute within the RouteOne component then data transition is called again on RouteOne. This behaviour not happening for you?

Comment: Weird, that isn't expected behavior.  Sorry man thought I had it there!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will stick with the bandaid for now.